# how to find exit status of second last command?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to make a script where I strictly want to control the standard output. so I am redirecting everything to /dev/null and printing my own messages.

## Example:

```
 user@root> tar zxvf samplefile.tar;> /dev/null 2>&1 ;echo $?  

 gzip: stdin: not in gzip format  
 tar: Child returned status 1  
 tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors  
 0
```

tar command failed but $? is storing exit status of redirection.  I want exit status of tar command.

## Query:

How can I get the status of tar command also redirect all std output to /dev/null?

Comment: The problem is the semicolon after the file name.  It separates commands.  Instead say: `tar zxvf samplefile.tar > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: it is because you wrote `tar zxvf samplefile.tar;`. Just remove semicolons, and it will remove messages and display the right `$?` value

Comment: Thanks devnull ,Subbeh and Ploutox. It worked.

Comment: @user2809888 Could you add the answer as a real answer below so the question is not being marked as unanswered, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Subbeh and Ploutox, I should not have used ";" in between the two commands.after removing ";" ,redirection became part of the orignal command and gave the correct return code.

However I am still not sure what could be used if we need to get exit status of ($?-1).